# Can I set the thread pool size for SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and each test case in a class appears to create a new thread. Is it possible to limit the size of the thread pool available to the runner?

Answer (score 0):

This is not purpose of this class. You can configure parallelism of your tests either in your IDE or rather in maven surefire plugin: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: I'm running the tests with gradle, and I don't have surefire as a dependency. I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: Then check this page: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#setMaxParallelForks(int)